# Python download

Tags: python, http, download

I'd like to download a file present at follow [link](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TEN.MI?period1=1451602800&period2=1569708000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=NZczOoN5ibT)

But the follow code python get me the error "HTTPError: Unauthorized":

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TEN.MI?period1=1451602800&period2=1569708000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=NZczOoN5ibT'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/dati/xxx.csv')
```

In reality it is not necessary a password to download the file.

Comment: If you're using same browser - it's not necessary to authorize, cause you already are. Take a look on response `description "Invalid cookie"`, which means that it requires some cookies.

Comment: I do not use a browser, I'd like to obtain the file in a path, directly from python

Comment: then you'll need to use a requests sessions object or similar to get the cookie and pass it to the url

Comment: would you know how to correct the code I wrote?

Answer (score -1):

[Your URL](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TEN.MI?period1=1451602800&period2=1569708000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=NZczOoN5ibT) requires a cookie. You can reproduce this by using the incognito mode.

Comment: incognito mode doesn't have anything to do with generating cookies

Comment: I do not use a browser, I'd like to obtain the file in a path, directly from python